# Managing Server side and Client side state after POST and DELETE

Tags: reactjs, rest, architecture, http-post, client-server

So here is the issue i am facing on deciding, Would like to know what is the best practice and which one to choose.

Suppose we have a list of items we use GET to get all the lists and we do  POST for editing and DELETE for deleting a list. After successful completion of either of these request whats the best practices to make sure client state is in sync with server state.

1. GET to fetch all the lists
2. let server return all the lists after edit or delete operations.
3. or client should trust 200 OK and update the client state with modifying lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very opinion-based, as there are lots of variables in play here.  Ideally I'd always say, drop the client-state, and always re-get the data after updates.  This of course completely depends on the cost/complexity of re-retrieving that state.  If it is cheap/small, go ahead and re-GET the lists... it's far simpler than trying to maintain state synchronization.  If you DO update a local cache, make sure it's a CACHE pattern, and not a REPOSITORY pattern.  This means you shouldn't necessarily trust the cache for important operations, and that you should do things like verify the entities before operating on them.

I would not return updated lists from a POST/DELETE, updated entities is fine, but the whole list should be a subsequent GET.  Anything else and you are not only breaking REST, but you are also defining the behavior of the client application in your service (which you don't want to do).